# SQL Server - Select Multiple Rows Data From One Table And Update Multiple Rows Data On Another Table With First Selected Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I am going to explain it as simple as possible. Now I have a `table_1` which has `price` and `itemId`. I also have another table `table_2` which has `totalprice,itemId`.

What I want to do is to sum all `price` from `table_1` grouped by `itemId` and update that sum of price in `table_2` with `itemId` key as the common column.

The price per `itemId` summed from `table_1` should update the `totalprice` column in `table_2`.

Is that possible ? Thank you.

SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes is it possible. You can do like this:

```
update T2
set totalprice = T1.totalprice
from Table_2 as T2
  inner join (select sum(price) as totalprice,
                     itemid
              from Table_1
              group by itemid) as T1
    on T2.itemid = T1.itemid
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119388/

If you don't already have all itemid's in table_2 you can use a [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) to update the existing rows and add a new row if it is missing.

```
merge Table_2 as T2
using (select sum(price) as totalprice,
              itemid
       from Table_1
       group by itemid) as T1
on T1.itemid = T2.itemid
when matched then 
  update set totalprice = T1.totalprice
when not matched then 
  insert (totalprice, itemid) 
  values(T1.totalprice, T1.itemid);
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119389/

Comment: trying to make it work. currently giving error. T1 does not have totalprice colum.

Comment: Awesome working now :) The naming is the key. Like as T1 and T2